# Counting records with an Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, inner-join

I have a query where I am trying to count the number of calls each employee has made.  However, the Employee's name is not in the Call's table so I had to use an Inner Join.  Here is what I have so far.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
Select e.Name, count(1)
From Employees e INNER JOIN Calls c on c.EmployeeID = e.TechID
Where(c.Name LIKE 'John ') OR 
     (c.Name LIKE 'Sam ') OR 
     (c.Name LIKE 'Bob ') OR 
     (c.Name LIKE 'Mark') OR 
     (c.Name LIKE 'Mike')  
Group By e.Name
```

Essentially I am looking for two columns, the Employee's name and the number of calls they have made.

The query will run but it goes for a VERY long time, until I finally kill it.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does the execution plan say? Which DBMS are you using (Postgres, Oracle, Firebird, ...)

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008 r2

Comment: Having to perform join before you can search is always a performance killer, especially your "calls" table sounds like a million record rows. Probably one way you can make it faster is to build index on employee's name column, get all the employee ids which name LIKE John, Sam, Bob etc, then use this group of ids to select Calls table without having to join

Comment: Is your query correct? Shouldn't it be e.Name rather than c.Name in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Select e.Name, count(*) Total_Calls
From Employees e INNER JOIN Calls c on c.EmployeeID = e.TechID
Where c.Name IN ('John ','Sam ','Bob ','Mark ','Mike ')  
Group By e.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the aggregating in a sub query and then joining that to the employee table.

```
SELECT 
    A.[Name],
    B.[CallCount]
FROM [Employees] A
INNER JOIN (SELECT [EmployeeID], COUNT(*) [CallCount] FROM [Calls] GROUP BY [EmployeeID]) B
ON      A.[TechID] = B.[EmployeeID]
WHERE   A.[Name] LIKE 'John '
     OR A.[Name] LIKE 'Sam '
     OR A.[Name] LIKE 'Bob '
     OR A.[Name] LIKE 'Mark'
     OR A.[Name] LIKE 'Mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gerrytan. Your string processing (grouping and searching) is the culprit. You can store the id for the employees in the search criteria in a temp table and then in your main query you should group by employee id and find ids that match in temp table

```
CREATE #temptable
(int id)


SELECT e.Id
INTO #temptable
FROM Employees e
WHERE (e.Name LIKE 'John ') OR 
     (e.Name LIKE 'Sam ') OR 
     (e.Name LIKE 'Bob ') OR 
     (e.Name LIKE 'Mark') OR 
     (e.Name LIKE 'Mike')  


Select e.Name, count(1)
From Employees e INNER JOIN Calls c on c.EmployeeID = e.TechID
Where e.Id IN (
   SELECT Id FROM #temptable
)
Group By e.Id
```